# Docker installation on 16.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-16.04

How to install docker on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/ covers 16.04

Comment: Also please let me know if you have any article to install a docker private registry on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest would be to run this in your bash terminal: `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

You can look at these for instructions:-

- [Docker installation using script](https://get.docker.com/)
- [Official documentation to
  install docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/)

For installing private docker registry, use this link. It should work fine for ubuntu16.04:-

- [Docker private registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you can install Docker by:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

Keep in mind that when installing Docker in Ubuntu, you just install Docker, but when you install it on Windows 10 and Mac OS X, it installs also `docker-compose` and `docker-machine`.

If you also want to install `docker-machine` run: (if you want a different version change `v0.12.2` to the version you want)

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.12.2/docker-machine-`uname -s`-`uname -m` >/tmp/docker-machine &&
chmod +x /tmp/docker-machine &&
sudo cp /tmp/docker-machine /usr/local/bin/docker-machine
```

Finally, if you also want to install `docker-compose`, replace, and run: (if you want a different version change `1.15.0` to the version you want)

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.15.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose &&
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```